# Is there a way in Blender 2.8.1 to use indexed colors in vertex painting

Tags: vertex-colors

I am looking for a way to do vertex painting in Blender with indexed colors, so that one could have a palette of colors and assign a index of those colors to a vertex. This would enable a way to easily change colors in a set of vertices. Is there a way to do this already in Blender 2.8.1-> , or a plugin that could be used?

Comment: Can add a palette to a brush. As long as panting brush gives all or nothing result, ie the vert color is exactly set or not. then assigning (or evaluating) an index to color from palette is relatively simple (addon code wise)... recall something similar..?  Assigning in edit mode on a vert selection basis would be, IMO, be  easiest to implement.